# Some homebrew formulas broken after migration

Tags: homebrew, migration

I've migrated from an old MacBook Pro to a new one, using Apple's Migration assistant. Some home-brew formulas migrated with no problem, whereas others got broken at the library reference level. Reinstalling them does not help. E.g.:

```
$ weechat
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/weechat
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

But

```
$ brew install weechat
Warning: weechat 2.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.2, run `brew reinstall weechat`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend going with what the message says, i.e. reinstall the formula and that should take care of things. If I were you, I'd reinstall all the installed formula.

Comment: Thanks, @NimeshNeema. I tried to do that. The install process works well, but running weechat (and many other programs) ends with the same error message shown above.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem, what I did was i run

```
brew list -1 > brew.txt # list out all installed packages
brew list -1 | xargs brew rm --force # remove all installed packages
brew install $(cat brew.txt | tr '\n' ' ') # install all previously installed packages
```

If everything went fine, remove the package list by:

```
rm brew.txt
```

You should probably check potential warnings as well.

Comment: Life saver solution

Comment: So... after a Migration Assistant install (at least for Catalina, my current system): one has to ** reinstall ALL Homebrew packages **?  Like EVERY package?  (That takes a looong time on my system.)  What is the nature/reason for such a drastic requirement?  (Have the Apple security folks maybe gone a bit overboard...??)

Answer (score 13):

**Yes doing the following will fix it**

```
brew uninstall --force gettext
brew install gettext
```

Answer (score 2):

Likely problem with libintl.8.dylib as in many other similar issues:

```
brew uninstall --force gettext
brew install gettext

locate libintl.8.dylib
```

if /gettext//libintl.*.dylib exists

```
brew link -f gettext
```

go to (depending on version)

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew 
cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
```

and execute (make sure you're in .../Homebrew directory)

```
git pull origin master
rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
brew update && brew upgrade
```

this last will took some time, but afterwards everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Re-install the missing libraries, on a one-by-one basis.

For example:

```
$ weechat
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/weechat
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Means that `gettext` is missing. So:

```
$ brew install gettext
```

and try again. This time it will fail because of another missing library, but after all libraries have been installed, the application will run.

Comment: This is what I had to do.  I did make the brew.txt file as mentioned by @maricn.  But it kept failing on so many packages that I would remove those lines, save and try again.  Eventually I got it working